# how to document QML files inside C++ project?

Tags: c++, qt, qml, documentation, doxygen

I am working on a C++ project with qml files. I have documented C++ files using doxygen but in the same project, I'm also having many .qml files. For documenting qml files, I instlaled doxyqml.

My requirement is C++ files and qml file should be documented separately. Issue I'm facing is, this project is having all C++ and qml files with same name like Login.cpp, Login.qml, DatabaseHandler.cpp, DatabaseHandler.qml, likewise all the .cpp and .qml files are having same name. So when I'm trying to document, whichever files having same names, both the C++ and qml content are documented in single class Login, DatabaseHandler, etc.
But I need to document C++ class as separate class and qml class as separate class although they have same name.

Can anyone help me how to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

Doxyqml turns .qml files into C++ description and feeds it to doxygen. The latter of course cannot separate generated files from the rest.

https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/trouble.html

> Doxygen does not work properly if there are multiple classes, structs
> or unions with the same name in your code. It should not crash
> however, rather it should ignore all of the classes with the same name
> except one.

the only way is to have two separate doxygen project, one for qml only. It's recommended to refactor code.